# Alarm creation at this instant android studio

Tags: android, alarm, android-alarms

When battery percentage reaches 100, I want to ring an alarm. How can I solve that?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    int percentage = level*100/scale;

    TextView t = ((MainActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText(Integer.toString(percentage)+"%");
    if (percentage==100)
        //ring alarm
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Abhinav. It depends on the requirements, but I would probably consider sending a 'Notification' with a sound.  By using a Notification, it both makes the user aware why the alarm sound is ringing and gives them a chance to cancel the sound.

Comment: I want to do the same, but how can I do it at that particular instant, in alarmManager every thing is like after some time or specific date etc.

Comment: It is difficult to answer without seeing more of the code. But in general, actively monitoring the battery is not encouraged because it usually does more harm than good. It is increasingly difficult to do in modern Android. Google are instead trying to make developers only monitor significant changes via broadcasts such as android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW. Unfortunately, for your use case, they do not include one for FULL. I guess you would need to use a JobScheduler/WorkManager or as a last resort a Foreground Service because registering to receive battery level changes must be done in code.

Comment: Hi Abhinav. I've added the code for ringing the alarm. if you have any questions related to how the service should monitor the battery, please raise them as a separate [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]). I have only included the solution for where your code stops at: "// ring alarm" because we try to keep 1 specific answer for 1 specific question to make information easy to find on StackOverflow. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite: Copy the .mp3 sound that you want to play to res/raw
[Create the "raw" directory if necessary]

Here is the commented source which was taken from the latest Android examples and modified to play the custom sound:

```
private final static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 128;
private final static String CHANNEL_ID = "com.elletlar.stackoverflow.notification_test";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_java);

    Notification notification = createNotification();

    // Issue the notification.
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}

private Notification createNotification() {
    createNotificationChannel();

    final Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.elletlar.stackoverflow/" + R.raw.sound);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("The content")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setSound(soundUri);
    return builder.build();
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        final Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.elletlar.stackoverflow/" + R.raw.sound);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();
        channel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);


        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

A Couple of notes:

- Many of the Notification examples on StackOverflow no longer work due to Google adding the NotificationChannel concept from Android O
- From Android O the sound must be set on the Notification Channel, previously it was set on the Notification itself
- If you don't have a sound available, just use: `Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);` instead